# selenium returns an error when trying to open a web

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

error:

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61426/devtools/browser/240a1fed-24b5-4ff2-a1b8-3f49803e96b8
[7276:4992:0203/194852.953:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [19:48:52.955] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
[7276:4992:0203/194852.953:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [19:48:52.957] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)
[7276:4992:0203/194852.953:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [19:48:52.957] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: Uno de los dispositivos conectados al sistema no funciona. (0x1F)

code:

````
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path="~\Chisco\Desktop\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.get("https://www.meteogalicia.gal/observacion/estacionshistorico/historico.action?idEst=19008&request_locale=es#")


# Crea un objeto WebDriverWait y espera hasta que el elemento con ID "lugo" esté disponible
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) # 10 segundos de tiempo de espera
radio_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "lugo")))
radio_button.click()```
````